# Why I can't use let in protocol in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, getter-setter, swift-protocols

I have a doubt about protocols in Swift about the use of **var** and the **keywords { get set }**.

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html):

> If a protocol requires a property to be gettable and settable, that
>   property requirement cannot be fulfilled by a constant stored property
>   or a read-only computed property. If the protocol only requires a
>   property to be gettable, the requirement can be satisfied by any kind
>   of property, and it is valid for the property to be also settable if
>   this is useful for your own code.
>
> Property requirements are always declared as variable properties,
>   prefixed with the var keyword. Gettable and settable properties are
>   indicated by writing { get set } after their type declaration, and
>   gettable properties are indicated by writing { get }.

I can't understand why I can't use **let**. A **var** in a protocol with only **get** isn't just a **let**?

Something like this:

```
protocol someProtocol 
{
   var someProperty: String { get }
}
```

it would not be just:

```
protocol someProtocol 
{
   let someProperty: String
}
```

I'm missing something?

Comment: a gettable property can still change values - the protocol implementor can always return different values, the protocol caller simply can't set them. let, on the other hand, defines a constant. it can only be set once and can not have a different value.

Comment: @pvg, why didn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: yup, this is the correct answer here.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov Answers to simple questions often end up a competition of who can type the wordiest, least comprehensible thing. For little things, easier to just comment. Also, lazy.

Comment: @pvg, I get your point.  One should please to be right.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

*"A var in a protocol with only get isn't just a let?"* No. A `let` indicates a constant. But that is not the case here. Consider the following:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var someProperty: String { get }
}

class SomeClass : SomeProtocol {

    var someProperty: String = ""

    func cla () {
        someProperty = "asd"
    }
}

let someInstance = SomeClass()

print(someInstance.someProperty) // outputs ""
someInstance.cla()
print(someInstance.someProperty) // outputs "asd"
```

The protocol specifies what the conforming class shows to the outside - some property of type `String` named `someProperty` which you can *at least* get.

If the protocol specifies `{ get }` your class can choose to conform via `let someProperty: String = ""` but it can similarly choose to conform via the above code. If on the other hand the protocol specifies `{ get set }` you cannot use `let` in the implementation but have to make it set-able as well.

A protocol simply cannot define that a value has to be constant - neither should it, that is an implementation detail that has to be taken care (or decided about) by the class / struct that implements it.

Comment: Looking back it was so simple and obvious, in protocols are allowed only functions (then properties) but I always prefer ask and solve any doubts; now the use of `{ get set }` it's clear as ever, thanks again!

Comment: _A protocol simply cannot define that a value has to be constant - neither should it_ Why Not? Why didn't Apple provide more granularity and allow to define both let and var properties? Or you're saying while Apple could have opted what I said, instead they opted that the flexibility to be given at the implementation level

Answer (score 56):

The difference is between

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    let someProperty: String
}
```

which makes no sense — a protocol isn't supposed to dictate *how* `someProperty` is defined/stored, only *that* it's available as a property. It could be either a computed or stored property, but that's for the implementer to decide, not the protocol itself.

and

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var someProperty: String { get }  // abstract interface
}

struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {
    let someProperty: String  // concrete implementation: stored property
}

struct OtherStruct: MyProtocol {
    let i: Int
    var someProperty: String { return "\(i)" }  // concrete implementation: computed property
}
```

which is perfectly allowed!

Comment: _a protocol isn't supposed to dictate how `someProperty` is defined/stored_ Doesn't a protocol define variable name/type/must be settable or not? Why didn't Apple provide more granularity and allow to define both let and var properties?

Answer (score 4):

I think a protocol can require that a structure has something, but it can't restrict functionality of struct or object. That shouldn't prevent you from doing what you'd probably like to do in code, for example using a `var` in the protocol and a `let` for the implementation is acceptable.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var trythis: Int { get }
}

struct MyStructure: MyProtocol {
    let trythis: Int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A property declared with `let` is considered `read-only` under the hood. For this reason, a protocol can require that a property be a constant by setting it read-only. This deduction can be verified using some of the `Objc` runtime functions  `property_getAttributes`.

```swift
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var someTypeProperty: Int { get }
}

struct Foo: SomeProtocol {
    let someTypeProperty: Int
}
```